# C# Property Grid Pass Constructor Variable

Tags: c#, propertygrid, system.componentmodel

I'm using the C# property grid to add new objects and change settings of a specific object.  I need to know how to pass a a variable to the constructor using the Component Model.  Reason why is because a parameter is required to correctly define the initial values of the chart object.

```
List<Chart> charts = new List<Chart>();
[Description("Charts")]
[Category("4. Collection Charts")]
[DisplayName("Charts")]
public List<Chart> _charts
{
    get { return charts; }
    set { charts = value ; }
}




public class Chart
{
    public static string collectionName = "";

     int chartPosition = GetMaxChartIndex(collectionName);
     [Description("Chart posiion in document")]
     [Category("Control Chart Settings")]
     [DisplayName("Chart Position")]
     public int _chartPosition
     {
         get { return chartPosition; }
         set { chartPosition = value; }
     }


    public Chart(string _collectionName)
    {
        collectionName = _collectionName;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is declare a custom [TypeDescriptionProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptionprovider.aspx) for the Chart type, early before you select your object into the PropertyGrid:

```
...
TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(new ChartDescriptionProvider(), typeof(Chart));
...
```

And here is the custom provider (you'll need to implement the CreateInstance method):

```
public class ChartDescriptionProvider : TypeDescriptionProvider
{
    private static TypeDescriptionProvider _baseProvider = TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(typeof(Chart));

    public override object CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type objectType, Type[] argTypes, object[] args)
    {
        // TODO: implement this
        return new Chart(...);
    }

    public override IDictionary GetCache(object instance)
    {
        return _baseProvider.GetCache(instance);
    }

    public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetExtendedTypeDescriptor(object instance)
    {
        return _baseProvider.GetExtendedTypeDescriptor(instance);
    }

    public override string GetFullComponentName(object component)
    {
        return _baseProvider.GetFullComponentName(component);
    }

    public override Type GetReflectionType(Type objectType, object instance)
    {
        return _baseProvider.GetReflectionType(objectType, instance);
    }

    public override Type GetRuntimeType(Type reflectionType)
    {
        return _baseProvider.GetRuntimeType(reflectionType);
    }

    public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, object instance)
    {
        return _baseProvider.GetTypeDescriptor(objectType, instance);
    }

    public override bool IsSupportedType(Type type)
    {
        return _baseProvider.IsSupportedType(type);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `_baseprovider` either not be static or set in a static constructor?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 - why not it's just a sample

Comment: Thanks for posting.  I'm not sure if this is going to help.  I do not understand the "TypeDescriptor.AddProvider" part.   All that I need to do is pass a parameter to the Chart class' constructor when the property  grid creates a new Chart object

Comment: You just can't do that.